# Java - Accessing Tomcat/Jersey url gives 404 Not Found

Tags: java, xml, rest, tomcat, jersey

I've been struggling with this for the past two hours. I've looked at many different StackOverflow answers (a lot of questions appear like this one) but not one of them worked for me.

I have a simple 'CountryResources' class, that uses the `@Path("/countries")`, but when I navigate to `localhost:8080/restservices/countries` it just gives me a 404 error.

CountryResource class, located in a worldmap.services package:

```
package worldmap.services;

import model.Country;
import model.CountryService;
import model.ServiceProvider;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder;
import javax.json.JsonObjectBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/countries")
public class CountryResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getCountries() {
        System.out.println("Opgehaald");
        CountryService cs = ServiceProvider.getWorldService();
        JsonArrayBuilder jab = Json.createArrayBuilder();

        for(Country c : cs.getAllCountries()) {
            JsonObjectBuilder job = Json.createObjectBuilder();
            job.add("code", c.getCode());
            job.add("name", c.getName());
            job.add("continent", c.getContinent());
            job.add("region", c.getRegion());
            job.add("surface", c.getSurface());
            job.add("population", c.getPopulation());
            job.add("government", c.getGovernment());

            jab.add(job);
        }
        JsonArray array = jab.build();
        return array.toString();
    }

}
```

Web XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>worldmap.services</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restservices/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors on startup? Did you check the server log?

Comment: There is no route at the root of your URL, so maybe you temporarily move the restservices there to test the rest of the code

Comment: Maybe you need to add the context path to the URL, which is usually the name of the project

Comment: @peeskillet I tried the url `localhost:8080/demoblog/restservices/countries` but that didn't work either. And I'm getting zero errors at startup. 

@cricket_007 I'm not quite sure what you mean, could you explain?

Comment: can you show your deployment folder ? the classes and the libraries. we can make sure if things are deployed correctly.

Comment: @ShivV I compared my files with the files of a university friend. It appears that within the Target>demoblog>WEB-INF>lib folder, files are not properly syncing! 

I 'fixed'  it by dragging all the .jar files that the friend had, into my lib folder and... IT WORKED! However, this is just a 'hack', I'm not sure how to properly fix it though.

I am using Intellij IDEA. Any ideas Shiv?

Comment: One of many ways is to mavenize your  project and then generate war and copy war to tomcat deployment directory but that's just my suggestion.

Comment: @ShivV I am already using Maven. And my TomCat server is integrated within IntelliJ, so I can just right-click 'index.html'  and press 'run' and it will start a TomCat instance.

I just can't seem to figure out why, upon start, all those library files don't copy over.

Comment: here is one link http://geekabyte.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-create-war-files-with-intellij.html?m=1 and look around stack overflow there are many answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been found: Maven is not copying the dependencies of the program to the target's lib folder. Will have to try and figure out how to fix that.